# Steam using wrong file association for inode/directory (kid3)

Tags: steam, mime-type, file-association

Kubuntu 16.04, latest Steam. kid3 is not a preferred application in both `/usr/share/applications/mimeapps.list` and `~/.config/mimeapps.list` and `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` is a symlink to `~/.config/mimeapps.list`. Where else is this association stored? Solution that does not require GUI apps is preferred. Editing files that belong to a package is not a solution as they will be rewritten on the next update.

Comment: xdg-open uses `run-mailcap` and that gives a wrong result somehow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution that worked for me was adding `~/.mailcap` with following contents:

```
inode/directory; XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=kde dolphin %s; test=test -n "$DISPLAY"
```